# When/why can INDEX replace ARRAYFORMULA?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I found that `INDEX()` can replace `ARRAYFORMULA()` in some situations.
I wonder this is a supported function of `INDEX` or just a bug since I cannot find any documentation of `INDEX` function working this way.

For example, these two formulae give the same result.

```
=INDEX(ArrayFormula(SPLIT (I2:I75," ")),,1)

=INDEX(SPLIT (I2:I75," "),,1)
```

However, without `INDEX`, `SPLIT(I2:I75," ")` gives only one result, not an array.

In the same way, `INDEX` can be used instead of `ARRAYFORMULA` with `VLOOKUP`.

[image: INDEX replaces ARRAYFORMULA]

The [G1] cell is calculated with a normal `ARRAYFORMULA`.

[image: ARRAYFORMULA]

Comment: Unclear: Why would it be disallowed that multiple functions have overlapping functionality? Or that a problem can only be solved in one manner..

Comment: Also, refrain from using “bug” without a *very specific demonstration and strong argument* - I’ve reworded the title. It might be good to better clarify this “behavior of index” in question. Consider that it could be the ‘context’ of split and misleading conclusion of what it returns..

Comment: Last I checked split and array formula are not an Excel formula. Please tag appropriately. @user2864740

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX` (same as `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` or `FILTER`) is "type" of `ARRAYFORMULA` which defines a restriction of the outputed array.

However, unlike `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`, in `INDEX` formula can those restrictions be partially or fully omitted. examples:

```
=INDEX(A:B)

=INDEX(A:B,,)

=INDEX(A:B,,1)

=INDEX(A:B, 10, 2)

=INDEX(A:B, 10, )
```

`SPLIT` function is able to return array of results on its own. example:

```
=SPLIT(A2, ",")
```

but when it is fed by range instead of single-cell reference it requires help to be able to roll out on all rows. example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A2:A20, ","))
```

the above is most common but if you prefer an alternative you can use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A20, ","))

=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(A2:A20, ","), 9^9, 1)

=FILTER(SPLIT(A2:A20, "I"), A2:A20<>"♪")
```